# Is it standard behavior to assign singleton variables (used only in unit testing) in a controller?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, bdd

"myEvent" is fired when clicking on any div in a grid,

watching this event using:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function (e, info) {
    var someString = someStringHelper.convertToString(info);
    $scope.justToTest = someString;
    // Do stuff.
});
```

And it looks like someone is using $scope.justToTest as follows:

```
it('should handle myEvent events', function () {
    childScope.$apply(function () {
        childScope.$emit('myEvent', new generateStringKey("a", b, c));
    });
    expect(scope.justToTest).toBe('a-BEE-C');
    expect(scope.stringsList).toEqual(scope.otherStringsList[a-BEE-c]);
});
```

Comment: What is the "singleton variable" that is _only_ used in a test?  Do you mean the `$scope` property `justToTest`.  This looks like example code, not something that would be used in a real application.

Comment: This looks more like a misplaced test for `someStringHelper.convertToString` to be honest.

Comment: @Davin Tryon - Yes I'm referring to "justToTest," and not that it matters, but to respond to your other comment: Sadly it's in a very real application.  I'm just trying to find out how my predecessor set it up and didn't find much on Google.

Comment: @Bart It's a misplaced test alright, I'm not sure exactly how or why someone would write a test just to see if an event fired.  The test, if anything, should have tested the results of the actual object used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I would not say it is typical (or a good idea) to have properties on the scope that are not needed.

For this specific example, it is fine for the test to fire the event, but the test should be testing the effect of the event on 'real' properties that are used.

So, the overall structure of the test looks correct. But the expectation should only apply to `scope.stringsList`.  And `justForTest` should be taken out.

Comment: Yes it is important to differentiate between asking "Is this possible?" and "Is there any good reason to do this?"  In this case I'm asking the latter.  Thanks for being sharp and picking up on that =]